# uniq multiple dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need to merge following two arrays into a single array.

It looks like `array_merge` not support multiple dimensional array.

**Courses**

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Name] => Course1 [CourseId] => 1 [Selected] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [Name] => Course2 [CourseId] => 2 [Selected] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [Name] => Course3 [CourseId] => 3 [Selected] => ) 
[3] => Array ( [Name] => Course4 [CourseId] => 4 [Selected] => ) 
[4] => Array ( [Name] => Course5 [CourseId] => 5 [Selected] => )
)
```

**TeacherCourses**

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [CourseId] => 1 [Selected] => selected) 
[1] => Array ( [CourseId] => 2 [Selected] => selected) 
[2] => Array ( [CourseId] => 3 [Selected] => selected) 
)
```

**I need this result**

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Name] => Course1 [CourseId] => 1 [Selected] => selected) 
[1] => Array ( [Name] => Course2 [CourseId] => 2 [Selected] => selected) 
[2] => Array ( [Name] => Course3 [CourseId] => 3 [Selected] => selected) 
[3] => Array ( [Name] => Course4 [CourseId] => 4 [Selected] => ) 
[4] => Array ( [Name] => Course5 [CourseId] => 5 [Selected] => )
)
```

Comment: foreach loops are sufficient for this task

Comment: Like two foreach loops?

Comment: yes, you would have to use foreach loop, but not twice, just have a look at the answer i have just posted below :)

Comment: If those two arrays are results from SQL queries, it would be even more efficient (faster) to "merge" them in SQL.

Comment: @user4456456 yes you could, anyway where are your attempts?

Comment: @user4456456, just try the answer mentioned below: it should help for u for sure.

Comment: There is a problem. I don't get all the courses. Only the Courses the teacher have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **foreach** loop?

Here we go,:

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    foreach($arr2 as $value2){
        if($value['CourseId'] === $value2['CourseId']){
            $arr1[$key]['Selected'] = $value2['Selected'];
        }               
    }
}
```

hope this would help you.

keep coding :)

Comment: Assuming that `$arr2` is the second array in the OP's question, I'd have a few remarks. There will be an Error of the sort `Out of bounds` when you reach keys `3` and `4`. Why casting an array into array? And last, why casting the result of the merge array to an object?

Comment: yes it's the point, thanks Havelock, i have updated my code, may be this could help someone

Comment: almost there, just change the indices, and that unexplainable `Fag`, just add one in the key iteration

Comment: now i have expanded the code as much as i should, rest depends on coder's efforts.

Comment: There is a problem. I don't get all the courses. Only the Courses the teacher have.

Comment: @Amrinder Singh > I need all the courses and it says selected if the teacher have the course.

Comment: @user4456456 hii, here is the working example of the solution for your problem, https://eval.in/242575

Comment: Dohh forgot to edit to $arr1 in the if statement. Thx :)